# Given probabilities and elementary events , is the argument correct?

Tags: probability

Let A , B , E events such that P(A) = 0.7, P(B) = 0.5 , P(E) = 0.5 such that the elementary constitutive events are :
C1 = A' ∩ B' ∩ E' , C2 = A ∩ B ∩ E' , C3 = A ∩ B' ∩ E' , 
C4 = A ∩ B' ∩ E , C5 = A' ∩ B' ∩ E
Question: Is the argument correct ?

A', B' , E' : are the complimentary events
I have noticed from C1 that A, B and C are not exhaustive and from the given elementary events I have noticed that:
B can't occur alone
B and E can't occur together
A , B and E can't occur together.

Any hint how to solve this question ?

Comment: No, verify whether $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4,C_5$ are disjoint and exhaustive, and that there are unions of them which comprise each of $A,B,E$ and their complements.

Comment: I verified that C1,C2,C3,C4,C5 are disjoint but they are not exhaustive because there are missing elementary events like : (A ∩ B ∩ E) , (A' ∩ B ∩ E') and (A' ∩ B ∩ E) , is that right ?

Comment: So far so good.  Next, verify if those event *may* be measure zero.

Comment: By "verify if those events may be measure zero" you mean the events ;C1,C2,C3,C4,C5 ?